# Vuetify tab not changing on @click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using vueitfy version 2.3.10 and vue 2.6. I am using tabs component of vuetify. I am trying to add a button to switch between tabs. But the button doesn't change the tab. But I am able to change the tabs by clicking on the tab names. Please help me find where I am going wrong.

```
<template>
    <v-card>{{current_tab}}
        <v-tabs v-model="current_tab">
          <v-tab href="#tab-1">Organisations</v-tab>
          <v-tab href="#tab-2">Locations</v-tab>
          <v-tab-item value="tab-1" id="tab-1">
            <p>Organsations</p>
            <v-btn @click="nextTab('tab-2')">
              Locations
            </v-btn>
          </v-tab-item>
          <v-tab-item value="tab-2" id="tab-2"> 
            <p>Locations</p>
            <v-btn @click="nextTab('tab-1')">
              Organisations
            </v-btn>
          </v-tab-item>
       </v-tabs>
     </v-card>
</template>


<script>

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      current_tab: 'tab-1',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    nextTab(next_tab) {
      this.current_tab = next_tab
    }
  }
};      
</script>
```

Comment: it works fine [here](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/dyMjVBj)

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Dont know what wrong on my end.

Comment: do you have errors in console?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I am printing the value of the current_tab in v-card just to check if the current_tab changes value. In the nextTab, the current_tab value does change value but in the layout where I am printing the current_tab value it shows tab1

Comment: @user12763413 You should create a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim someone else faced this issue too. Not sure how can I fix it in my case. https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/10181. Please have a look.

Comment: @marsnebulasoup https://codepen.io/thebspin/pen/rNadpGZ?editable=true&editors=101
Something like this

Comment: Isn't the problem because there are three tabs and when you click the button it attempts to navigate to the nonexistent tab-4? See line 81 in the codepen link you sent. [This cycles between the tabs on click](https://codepen.io/marsnebulasoup/pen/QWNBONN?editors=1011)

Comment: @marsnebulasoup it is not same problem but somewhat similar